# Render not reflecting changes in functional component after state update

Tags: reactjs, state, rendering, spread-syntax

In ReactJS, within a functional component I am able to get some data from the server, and set it to state. Once this happens though, it is not updating my rendered component. Is this related to the way i'm setting the state, or something else? I have scraped some stuff out of this file since its large, but let me know if I need to provide more code to see whats going on. The data that comes back from the fetch is an array of one element that is a two property object, similar to the default value of the state:
[{"id":2,"companyName":"ChrisCo"}]

```
function Register({ history }) {
    const initialValues = {
        company: '',
        title: '',
        firstName: '',
        ...
    };

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([{id: 1, companyname: 'Select Company..'}]);

useEffect(() => {
    getCompanies();
} , []);

function getCompanies(){
    accountService.fetchCompanies().then(x => setCompanies([...x]))
    setLoading(false)
} 
if(loading)
        return (
        <>
            Loading...
            <BallTriangle />
        </>)

 return (
                <Form>
                       <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Company</label>
                            <Field name="company" as="select" className={'form-control' + (errors.company && touched.company ? ' is-invalid' : '')}>
                                {
                                    companies.map((item, i) => (
                                        <option key={i} value={item.id}>{item.companyname}</option>))
                                }
                            </Field>
                           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow genius, it was just a capital letter on companyname to companyName.
Javascript can be so unforgiving!
Sometimes it just takes posting it on stackoverflow and looking at your own question to realize the solution.